# Determine which IP address received a packet

Tags: sockets, boost-asio, winsock

I have a UDP server that listens on all IPv4 addresses, i.e. INADDR_ANY or 0.0.0.0. To every packet it receives from a client it shall respond with the IP address of the exact network interface that received the packet. Conceptually it should put the packet's source address into the packet's payload.

How do I know which source address will be used for sending a packet to a specific destination address when using `sendto()`? Do I need to enumerate all network interfaces manually, matching the network prefixes (or subnet-masked IPv4 addresses for that matter) to the destination address? If so, how? I would be interested in a cross-platform solution involving Boost.Asio but if that's not possible I need to use Winsock. In the future I might need a solution for Linux, too.

Answer (score 2):

> To every packet it receives from a client it shall respond with the IP address of the exact network interface that received the packet.

That is not something you typically need to handle manually.  If you simply have `sendto()` send a packet to the sender's IP/Port that `recvfrom()` reported, the OS will route the packet for you, based on which interface has an available route to that sender.

> How do I know which source address will be used for sending a packet to a specific destination address when using `sendto()`?

You can use `setsockopt()` to enable the `IP_PKTINFO` option on the listening UDP socket, and then use [`WSARecvMsg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms741687(v=vs.85)) (Windows) or [`recvmsg()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg) (Linux) instead of `recvfrom()`.  That will give you access to an `in_pktinfo` struct that tells you the destination IP that the received packet was sent to, and which interface actually received it.

Comment: This is great news! I did not know about `recvmsg()`/`WSARecvMsg()`. I guess this would also work with a non-IPV6_V6ONLY socket and return IPv4-mapped addresses, right? The reason I am doing this is to support some shitty protocol, otherwise I would only use `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` as you suggested.

Comment: @purefanatic for an IPv6 socket (whether you have `IPV6_V6ONLY` enabled or not), you need to enable the `IPV6_PKTINFO` (Windows) or `IPV6_RECVPKTINFO` (Linux) option, and then `WSARecvMsg()`/`recvmsg()` will give you an `in6_pktinfo` struct instead of an `in_pktinfo`.

Comment: I see. I forgot to mention one usecase though: The client might use a broadcast address to reach the server. In this case the server should still send a unicast response but the information gained from `recvmsg()` would not be very helpful as it would return the original broadcast address, or no?

Comment: @purefanatic It would give you the broadcast IP used, yes. But it would still give you the specific interface that the broadcast was received on, and you would still have the sender's IP/port, too. So, if needed, you could bind a separate socket to that interface and use it to send back to that sender. Otherwise, like I said, just send back to the sender using the receiving socket and let the OS handle the routing for you.